# How to use attribute in custom settings?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

How to use "accept" attribute in custom settings?

Give me some idea, this is my code:

```
 <apex:inputFile value="{!file.versionData}" accept=".xlsx,.xls" fileName="{!file.pathOnClient}" styleClass="slds-button--brand"  onchange="showbutton()" /
```

Comment: I think you can put validation using JavaScript. Populate Apex variable in javaScript and use it.